# StackOverflow API for R?

Tags: feature-request, support, api

Is there an R package for accessing the StackOverflow questions, answers, user profiles, badges, etc. through an API?  I would like to make a word cloud of popular tags and other such plots.

Comment: You mean an API for Stack Exchange Data Explorer ? http://data.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You would probably have the most luck downloading a StackExchange query into a CSV file, and then reading it from there into R

Comment: [Doesn't appear to exist yet](http://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/library+r) - but the [methods you want](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs) for what you describe are _very_ easy to use. Data dumps might be more useful for you - I'm not overly familiar with R.

Comment: Using a RESTful Web Service to grab the Stack Exchange Data Explorer collections and converting them locally to CSV's should do the job. No extra API's needed.

Comment: I've duplicated this thread on the regular StackOverflow page, so for those interested, check it out, too:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789264/stackoverflow-api-for-r

Comment: @GlennStrycker That question is not constructive.  Please don't ask questions of that nature on the main site.

Comment: Ugg, someone deleted it.  There were useful links and posts there, too.

Comment: [link one](https://api.stackexchange.com/) [link two](https://github.com/trinker/SO_scrape/blob/master/functions.R) [link three](https://github.com/trinker/SO_scrape/blob/master/scraping.R) [link four](http://stackoverflow.com/about)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There have been several attempts at providing such access to the API from R :

- `overflowr` is *"an R package to pull data from the StackExchange
  API"*, but it hadn't been updated since 2010 :
  https://code.google.com/p/overflowr/source/list
- `RStackExchange` is also an *"R based StackExchange client"*, but
  hadn't been updated for 2 years, too :
  https://github.com/geoffjentry/RStackExchange
- More recently, some active members of the StackOverflow `r` tag have
  begun developping an R package called `oveRflow`, which is *"An R
  package to assist people answering R questions on Stack Overflow"*.
  There is no interface to the API yet, but the development is active
  and open : https://github.com/sebastian-c/oveRflow

Answer (score 5):

This package might serve your purpose - [stackr: an R package for connecting to the Stack Exchange API](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) .